# Hover effect on first Div activating :after Element on second Div

Tags: html, css, hover

I need a hover effect on one div activating an ::after element placed on a second div.

Here my code:

```css
a{
  color:green;
}
     
 div.one:hover div.two::after {
  color: red;
  content:"Zusatztext";
 }
```

```html
   <a href="#">
      <div class="one">
        Text1
      </div>
      <div class="two">
        Text2
      </div>
   </a>
```

My guess is, that it doesn't work because the second div is not a descendant element of the first div, right?

I can place the :hover effect on a (the link) and it works.

This here does work:

```
a:hover div.two::after {
      color: red;
     content:"Zusatztext";
 }
```

Kind regards,
Milan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `+` between the selectors will achieve the result you are looking for. It is called [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

That will work if the sibling is immediately after the first element if you would need to add more elements in between you would use `~`. [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Try this:

```css
a{
    color:green;
}

div.one:hover + div.two::after {
      color: red;
     content:"Zusatztext";
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="one">
    Text1
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    Text2
  </div>
</a>
```